# Keeping navigation controller between storyboards (swift)

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I am creating an app with multiple storyboards. Right now, I am able to transition from the first storyboard to the second but when I transition to the second storyboard, I lose my navigation controller. However, I still need to navigate back to the first storyboard and would like to use the same controller. Does anyone know how to keep my navigation controller between storyboards?

Here's how I'm transitioning to my second storyboard. The pushViewController is my attempt to add to the navigation stack, but it doesn't work.

```
 let destination = UIStoryboard(name: "Preferences", bundle: nil)
 let initialViewController = destination.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(initialViewController, animated: true)
 self.presentViewController(initialViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think U just add redundant code.
delete

```
self.presentViewController(initialViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

this code will present View not in the navigation container starker. This code make

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController
```

do not work.

So just use

```
 let destination = UIStoryboard(name: "Preferences", bundle: nil)
 let initialViewController = destination.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(initialViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: You are right about the code repetition. Though it turns out that my problem was that self.navigationController was returning nil because I hadn't embedded it properly. Thanks for answering!